# Tooltip Showing Metadata for Target

Tags: .net, html, sitefinity, sitefinity-5

I am using Sitefinity CMS to build my website; for certain pages I use metadata like title and description which I enter through Sitefinity. If someone hovers over a menu item and it has metadata then it is shown in the tooltip.

I know that the reason for this is that whenever Sitefinity publishes a page it associates all possible data in all possible places - in the link that it generates the  tag has a title="" element.

I have no idea how to turn this feature off. I cannot manually cut out the metadata from the link and I still want the metadata associated with the page for search engines. Does anyone know an easy way to stop or modify this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up solving the problem by using

```
$("document").ready(function() {
$(".rsmItem a").attr("title", "");
});
```

and linking to jQuery beforehand. The problem was that Sitefinity was not updating the page late enough, the script to remove titles would run but not update anything that loaded after the script ran. I hope that if someone else has a similar problem this helps them out as well.

Answer (score 1):

> in the link that it generates the tag has a title="" element

Which link do you mean? If you are talking about the HTML that is generated by the Navigation widget - the link that is rendered depends on the type of navigation used. You can generally edit the markup through the widget template. For the Navigation widget, the only way is to use an external template. You can specify that through the widget properties:
[image]

Some of the controls in the template are required, so you would probably need the default template. You can get that from the Sitefinity SDK. All default widget templates come in a zip file, located in the installation folder, under /Content/Resources.

If you are not using the Navigation widget, please say which are the links to the pages that you want to modify.